# How to query numeric values as string with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

After switching to Eloquent, when querying our database the values are automatically cast to numeric data types. This results in strange values like `8.0000000000000002E-2` instead of `0.08`. This causes all sorts of issues with our reporting system. **Is there a flag that can be set to retrieve the values as strings?**

We've tried using casts in the Eloquent Model but that seems to happen after the fact. Adding rounding on the web side would be a very significant effort.

Example Query via `DB::select($query);`

```
SELECT (CAST(0.08 as float)) as ex1,
(CAST(0.04 as float)) as item2
```

The casts are to imply the data is stored as float in the database. These are custom queries and therefore are not using querybuilder on them.

Results in:

```
8.0000000000000002E-2    4.0000000000000001E-2
```

If you were to run this query directly in MSSQL for example it would show 0.08 and 0.04 which is what our webserver also used to report. I get that floating point numbers have finite precision but we are looking for a solution to mirror the previous behavior.

Comment: _when querying our database the values are automatically cast to numeric data types._ Can you elaborate? What is the query and the format in which data is actually stored in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to `decimal` instead of `float`:

```sql
SELECT (CAST(0.08 as decimal)) as ex1,
(CAST(0.04 as decimal)) as item2
```

You may want to change your column types to be `decimal` too, especially if you're dealing with currency values.

[More about the `DECIMAL` type in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)